# Retrieve Extra parameters from Airflow Connection

Tags: python, airflow, connection, hook

I have a Snowflake connection defined in Airflow.[image]

I am selecting the user, password and schema using the below:

```
conn = BaseHook.get_connection("snowflake_conn")
conn.login
```

return the login (EXAMPLE in this case)

If I try to access the 'extra' parameters, it doesn't work.

```
conn = BaseHook.get_connection("snowflake_conn")
conn.role
```

returns a **AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'role'**

Is there any different way in which I could grab the extra parameters from Airflow Connection settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extra parameters stored into the `extra` field, for access to that parameters you need to convert it first from string to the python dictionary by use [`Connection.extra_dejson`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/connection/index.html#airflow.models.connection.Connection.extra_dejson) property

```py
conn = BaseHook.get_connection("snowflake_conn")
conn.extra_dejson.get("role")
```